# How to customize exception output using serilog

Tags: c#, logging, serilog, getseq, seq-logging

I'm using Serilog as my logging framework (with Seq as my log sink).  When logging exceptions I'm using something like:

```
log.Error(ex, "Operation Failed");
```

My application makes heavy use of async/await methods.  When unhandled exceptions occur the stack traces are very hard to read.  There is a nuget package that cleans up async stack traces (https://github.com/aelij/AsyncFriendlyStackTrace).  This creates an extension method to give you access to a modified/clean stack trace:

```
ex.ToAsyncString()
```

I'd like to be able to use this library to intercept the stack trace before it is written to Seq and instead log the clean/modified stack trace.

Is there a way with Serilog/Seq to control the exact output of the error string that is sent to the log sink?

Comment: when you put a breakpoint at `log.Error(ex, .....)` can you get at `ex.Message or InnerException` at this point..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps [enrichment](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment) might be helpful here. While not specifically discussed in that link, you can build custom enrichers:

```
public class ExceptionEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        if (logEvent.Exception != null)
        {
            // do something here

            propertyFactory.CreateProperty("ExtraExceptionDetail", extraDetail);
        }
    }
}
```

then...

```
var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.Seq(url)
    .Enrich.With<ExceptionEnricher>()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext();
```

I don't have any experience with the package you referenced, but this approach lets you intercept and modify/add/remove properties of the event before it's written to Seq.